# How do I apply a css style to a class that doesn't contain a subclass

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to set a style on the div in the first faq-category-group class without affecting the style of the faq-category-group inside a faq-category-indent. How can this be done?

The classes are auto-generated by a PHP module, so changing the class names to make the selectors easier isn't an option.

```
<div class="faq">
    <div class="faq-category-group">Content</div>

    <div class="faq-category-indent">
        <div class="faq-category-group">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @zanlok: The markup wasn't indented properly so it was being interpreted as HTML. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

By that structure, select only groups that are children of `<div class="faq">` and apply the styles which you don't want applied to indented groups. The groups that are contained in `<div class="faq-category-indent">` will not be affected.

```
.faq .faq-category-group {
    /* Styles for all groups */
}

.faq > .faq-category-group {
    /* Styles for non-indented groups */
}
```

This assumes you don't care about IE6, of course. Otherwise, another, more verbose solution is this:

```
.faq .faq-category-group, .faq .faq-category-indent .faq-category-group {
    /* Styles for all groups */
}

.faq .faq-category-group {
    /* 
     * Styles for non-indented groups.
     * Works because .faq .indent .group above is more specific than
     * this one, so the above rule will override this one.
     */
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/NY5WS) that covers both cases.

Comment: IE7 and IE8 also seem to have a problem with the first sample (at least as I tested them they did).

Comment: I'm sort of going to "stand corrected". When viewing your link I see it works. When pasting your style into my test, it does not work. I can't explain the reason for the difference, so I will conclude that my tests are not useful.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the difference in the classes individually:

```
.faq .faq-category-group
{
    color: #00ff00;
}

.faq .faq-category-indent .faq-category-group
{
    color: #0000ff;
}
```

This will force the one to be styled according to the parent `.faq` and the other according to the parent `.faq-category-indent`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.faq > .faq-category-group {
   /*style*/
}
```

should work

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: @Joel: No, `>` is a CSS2 selector. It only fails in IE <= 6.

Comment: @BoltClock - I just tested it in IE7 and IE8, and it failed.

Comment: > is definitely a CSS2 selector, there's not reason it should fail in IE7/8. A better question is, why are you even using IE7/8?

Okay, fine, defined two styles then - one like above without the > and another .faq * .faq-category-group that "rolls back" the styles in the previous

Comment: @Seth - Your condescending disdain for use of a browser apparently discounts individuals who are required to use a multitude of browsers for development. It is not your place to determine what browsers are or are not useful.

Comment: @Joel - My condescending tone comes from the fact that you criticize yet offer no new information. Thank you for pointing out that it doesn't work in IE, but it would be nice if you could offer a solution of your own instead of criticizing those of others. Thank you.